# Algorirmo de ordenamiento en C [BubbleSort], Error assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

Estoy intentando usar el método de la burbuja, le doy los números desordenados por un .txt con solo 6 números.

Entonces para ello, tengo que recorrer ese archivo linea por linea, y pasar esa linea a un arreglo y luego ordenarlos para escribirlo en otro .txt ordenadamente.

El problema es que cuando quiero asignar el valor linea por linea a un arreglo, me salen números grandes que no tiene relación al .txt. fichero.txt contiene los 6 numeros desordenados y debería arrojarlo ordenado en out.txt.

Hay un error que dice: "[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast", que hace referencia a esta linea de código: `aq[cont_filas]=linea;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 void bubble_sort(long a[], long n) {
   int i = 0, j = 0, tmp;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
               tmp = a[j];
               a[j] = a[j + 1];
               a[j + 1] = tmp;
           }
       }
   }
}



int main() {
    long n,i,k, largo = 5;
    long c;
    int cont_filas=0;
    int m;

    long a[largo];

    long aq[largo];
    char linea[largo];
    FILE *fich;
    fich = fopen("fichero.txt", "r");

    FILE *f2;
    f2 = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    //Lee línea a línea y escribe en pantalla hasta el fin de fichero

    while(fgets(linea, 1024, (FILE*) fich)) {
        cont_filas++;

        // int m= a[cont_filas];

         aq[cont_filas]=linea;

    //   printf("%s\n", aq[cont_filas]);


       // printf("LINEA: %s FIN_DE_LINEA\n", linea);
                  //printf(f2, "%s \n", wena);

    }
    //printf("TOTAL: %d ...\n", cont_filas);
    bubble_sort(aq, largo);


    for (c = 1; c <= largo; c++) {
    //long tt= aq[c];

    //fprintf(f2, "%d\n", tt);
    //printf("%s\n", aq[c]);


}
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(fich);

     return 0;
}
```

Ese es el código, estuve 3 horas tratando de ver que es pero al parecer me superó, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a imaginar que el fichero tiene un número en cada línea:

```
111
222
333
444
555
```

Cuando tu haces

```
fgets(linea, 1024, (FILE*) fich))
```

Estás leyendo una línea de ese archivo y almacenando su contenido en `linea`:

```
char* linea = "111";
```

Ahora vuelve a fijarte un poco en el código anterior... `linea` es de tipo **`char[]`**. Esto quiere decir que **almacena cadenas de caracteres**, no números. Para verlo en perspectiva:

```
 Numero                Tamaño cadena         Tamaño int    
 --------------        -------------         ----------
              0            2 bytes            4 bytes
           1234            5 bytes            4 bytes
      123456789           10 bytes            4 bytes
          -5605            6 bytes            4 bytes  
999999999999999           16 bytes           -- bytes (no entra en un `int`)
```

En una cadena de caracteres, una secuencia numérica no es más que la representación de cada digito por separado, mientras que en un tipo de dato numérico el número se codifica en binario.

Este detalle es importante. Indica que los números tienes que leerlos como tal en vez de como secuencias de caracteres:

```
for( int linea=0; linea<5; linea++)
{
  fscanf(fich, "%d", &aq[linea]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que deberías hacer es entender la alarma (warning). Una vez hecho, el resto llegará solo. Tal vez no entiendas el mensaje por estar en inglés:

> [Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.

Lo traduzco:

> [Alarma] la asignación crea un entero desde un puntero sin aplicar una transformación.

---

Veamos la instrucción que te marca el compilador:

```
aq[cont_filas]=linea;
```

Vemos que efectivamente se trata de una asignación, estás asignando `linea` a `aq[cont_filas]`. Dado que se crea un entero desde un puntero, podemos saber sin mirar la definición de las expresiones implicadas que `linea` será un puntero y `aq[cont_filas]` será un entero, vamos a comprobarlo.

La definición de `aq` nos indica que es una formación<sup>1</sup> de enteros largos:

```
long aq[largo];
```

La definición de `linea` nos indica que es una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres:

```
char linea[largo];
```

En C (Y otros lenguajes, como C++) el nombre de la formación equivale a un **puntero** al primer elemento de la formación, por lo que en la expresión que te señala el compilador estás asignando un puntero en un entero:

```
//                vvvvv <--- Esto es la formación 'linea' por lo que es un puntero a caracter ('char *').
   aq[cont_filas]=linea;
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//     \___ Esto es el elemento 'count_filas'-ésimo de 'aq', por lo que es un 'long'
```

En C es posible representar un puntero como un simple número ya que se la dirección de memoria en que se almacena un dato, para arquitecturas de 32 bits es un número entre 0 y 2<sup>32</sup> (4.294.967.296). Si haces esto, lo que almacenarás en el `long` será la dirección de memoria (no el valor) y por ello observarás que "*me salen números grandes*".

Si quieres guardar en `aq` el **valor** del número que tienes como **texto**, tendrás que hacer una conversión de datos como [`atol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) (`a`lphanueric `to` `l`ong):

```
aq[cont_filas] = atol(linea);
```

Además, substituye `long largo = 5;` por un `#define largo 5` pues de lo contrario estarás creando una formación de tamaño variable y ésto puede darte problemas, consulta [estos hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+vla) para saber por qué.

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.